# STL list<Object> iterator to change an object within the list

Tags: c++, list, object, stl, iterator

I'm an amateur so bear with me, but I've hit the end of my research with no solution for this.

This code complies fine but when I debug, it's apparent that the procedure exists upon reaching the for loop, and never executes what is within it (which is what I need to do).

```
void insertWord(list<Word> &words, string str)
{
    list<Word>::iterator itr;
    for (itr = words.begin(); itr != words.end(); itr++ ) //EXITS HERE
    {
        if (str == (*itr).aWord)
        {
            (*itr).iterateCount();
            return;
        }
        if (str > (*itr).aWord)
        {
            words.push_back(Word(str));
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand why the for loop is never executed. It just skips right to the end of the function.

NB: "Word" is a custom class to hold a string and an int(how many of that string there are).
If any more info is required please ask, I'm dying here!
Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the list contains elements?

Comment: according to the logic of your function, look like `return` should be changed to `continue`

Comment: Unrelated: you can write `itr->foo` instead of `(*itr).foo`.

Comment: I clearly need a coffee because I can't believe I didn't see that.
There isn't anything in it no, so I've added a words.empty() test to give it one element to start with.

Without having an element in it the iterator won't have anywhere to begin or end.

So obvious, thank you so much, I'm new to StackOverflow, how do I give you rep?

Comment: Are you trying to keep the list in sorted order or something? My guess is you really would want to use a `std::set<Word>`... then you can search the set using its `find()` member function without having to use a loop yourself, and if they're not found just insert them - it will stay sorted automatically.

Comment: @TonyDelroy: Looks like `std::set<std::pair<Word,int>>` would be a better choice as it looks like the count of the words is also required.

Comment: @jezpez: "*how do I give you rep?*": By upvoting answers. The problem, here, is that no-one actually answered: anyone just commented.

Comment: @juanchopanza pls reword and write a simple answer, then I can give you some sweet sweet rep!

Comment: Also, @TonyDelroy I would use set and find() but this is part of a larger assignment which requires the use of list exclusively. Good suggestion though.

Comment: @jezpez done. See answer below.

Comment: You don't need an explicit `empty` check in general, since iterators are indeed very happy to `begin()` an empty collection. An empty collection is simply one whose beginning equals its end. There is no *error* in your program, it just didn't align with your own expectations.

Comment: @Naveen: the code implies the `count` is currently a member of the Word class/struct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your list is empty, so `itr==words.end()` and the code in the loop never executes.

Comment: Looks like I'll have to wait till I get 15 rep myself before I can upvote :( But thanks heaps! I'll come back and upvote when I have 15

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `std::map`:

```
std::map<Word, int> histogram;

histogram[Word("hello")] += 1;
histogram[Word("hello")]++; //  equivalent

histogram[Word("vertigo")]++;
```